# Time Series Lag Features Extraction

Tags: python, time-series, feature-extraction

Trying to use the shift function for Feature Extraction to create 3 additional columns: same day last week, same day last month, same day last year. Data I am using is found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/mayank2896/bike-sharing/data)

Initially, I am trying to just use the shift function before creating a new column.

```
data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'])
data['year'] = data['timestamp'].dt.year
data['month'] = data['timestamp'].dt.month
data['day'] = data['timestamp'].dt.day

data['day'] = pd.to_datetime(data['day'])
data.info()

the_7_days_diff = data['day'] - data.shift(freq='7D')['day']
```

Getting an error "This method is only implemented for DatetimeIndex, PeriodIndex and TimedeltaIndex; Got type RangeIndex"

Any help would be appreciated to understand what i am doing wrong.

Comment: When you stated data.shift(..) you're actually shifting the whole dataframe. Try data["timestamp"].shift(freq="7D") (to get one week before) to get the number of day but 7d shifted instead; if you want the day of that just add .day to the method

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that `shift` is applied on the index of the dataframe, not the value. You need to set the `timestamp` column as index after converting it to datetime data type.

```
data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'])
data = data.set_index('timestamp')
week_diff = (data - data.shift(freq='7D')).dropna()
```